# Recovering a deleted view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

‎I have the following problem in my database in SQL Server.

‎I just right-clicked on a view and `CREATE`, looked at the script of the view and made a few adjustments. Then add and execute a `DROP "View_xy"` above the `CREATE`.‎

‎There was an error with the customizations, so the view was dropped, but the `CREATE` could not be executed. Because of all the fast fast I discarded my adjustments and closed the window.‎

‎Unfortunately, of course, the view is now deleted and the script is also gone.‎

‎Is there a way to restore the script of the view without resorting to the backup?‎

‎(*I want to avoid backup, because this booth is eve and I made many changes in other views today*)‎

‎Thank you in advance!‎

Comment: Source control is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restore a backup to a different database or server and extract the view definition from there.

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't think it's that easy!

Answer (score 0):

On as SQL214, I was able to restore a deleted view from the result set of this SQL:

```
SELECT  Convert(varchar(Max),Substring([RowLog Contents 0],33,LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))) as [Script]
FROM fn_dblog(DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
Where [Operation]='LOP_DELETE_ROWS' And [Context]='LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST'
And [AllocUnitName]='sys.sysobjvalues.clst'
```

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33766.sql-server-troubleshooting-how-to-recover-views-and-procedures-dropped-by-mistake.aspx